# Django custom user how to now link it FK

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have followed a tutorial on Django's new custom users and created the following...

app accounts:

```
class CompanyUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    """
    Concrete class of AbstractEmailUser.
    """
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have another package called `pages` with a model `class Pages`,  I now need to link the new type of user to this class. As its a separate package what would be the recommended way to do this?

i.e.

**Import CompanyUser and set FK as normal? Or create a generic relation on pages class for CompanyUser?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the the relation on the pages object rather than the user object. But if you want to put it there it better to use the AUTH_USER_MODEL from your settings

```
from django.conf import settings

...

class Pages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) # or models.OneToOneField(...)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model